# How to trigger the build only if master branch is tagged from Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

Currently, I have something similar to this setup.

[image]

This triggers the unsuccessful build and checks for the all the heads and branches and then stops. My point is it should not even trigger the build if I apply a tag to any other branch except Master and even tag should be in a standard format like x.x.x.

Currently, any tag on master triggers the successful build.

So to list down issues.

1. Trigger the build only if the master is tagged.
2. tag should be in the standard format like x.x.x

In any other case, build should not be triggered

Please check the image for reference. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tags are not related to branches, but to commits. "heads" (`refs/heads/*`) are "branches". The `master/tags/*` refspec is nonsense.

Comment: Please get a bit more familiar with Git and then rethink/rephrase, how your build process should look like.

Comment: I can only assume that you want to run the job, when the current tip of the master branch is tagged. So get the commit for the branch and figure out, if a tag in the appropriate format is associated with it. I doubt that you can solved this without code.